# How to convert initialized interface from parent interface back to child interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have created an interface in Typescript that looks like this:

```
export interface item{
    itemid: string,
    description: string,
    price: number,
}
```

and extended it with another interface that looks like this:

```
export interface itemBook extends item{
    booktitle: string,
    edition: number,
    course: string,
}
```

I've created an itemBook instance (tempBook) and declared it as an item to place it inside an array of item instances.  However, once I retrieve tempBook from the item array, it comes out out typed as an item with only item properties visible. Trying to retrieve the itemBook properties states that the itemBook properties are missing from the item interface, but trying to write a function that converts tempBook's type back to itemBook fails to resolve this. Checking in console shows that tempBook does have all itemBook properties both before and after attempting to convert tempBook.

The page I'm working with has a component that looks like this:

```
export class BrItemComponent implements OnInit {
   Item: item; 
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItem();
  }

  getItem():void{
    this.Item = tempBook
    this.setCategory(this.Item);
  }

  setCategory(Item: item):void  {
    var returnItem;
    if (Item.description == "book"){
        returnItem= Item as itemBook;
        this.Item = returnItem;
    }
    if (Item.description == "furniture"){
        returnItem = Item as itemFurniture;
        this.Item = returnItem;
    }
  }
```

Setting the initialized Item property to itemBook instances is not an option, as I intend to display several other item types (itemFurniture, itemSports, etc.) extended from the item interface using the same page.

How do I convert tempBook from it's parent item type back to it's original itemBook type so that I can access its' itemBook properties, or at the very least access the itemBook properties from it's parent interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're attempting to use the `description` property of `item` as a way of determining whether you have an `itemBook` or `itemFurniture`.

You'll probably want to look into using a discriminating (or disjoint) union.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

You can then define your interfaces like so

```
type itemShared = {
    itemid: string,
    price: number,
};

export type itemBook = itemShared & {
    description: 'book',
    booktitle: string,
    edition: number,
    course: string,
};

export type itemFurniture = itemShared & {
    description: 'furniture',
};

export type item = itemBook | itemFurniture;
```

So then in your `if` statements typescript will automatically figure out that if `description === 'furniture'` then its type is `itemFurniture`.